# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function anonymos function

Tags: javascript

```
function Human(name, currentMail, currentScore, newScore) {
   this.name = name;
   this.currentMail = currentMail;
   this.currentScore = currentScore;
   this.newScore = newScore;
   this.changeScore = function (ns) {
       if (ns != "") {
           console.log(ns + "Is Your New  Score");
           this.currentScore = ns;
       }
   };

   this.changeMail = function (cmail) {
       if (cmail != this.currentMail) {
           console.log(cmail + "Is Your New Mail");
           currrentMail = cmail
       };
   };
}
var ilan = new Human();
ilan = {
    name: "Ilan Vachtel",
    currentMail: "ilanvac@gmail.com",
    currentScore: "85"
};
console.log(ilan);
ilan.newScore = "89";
ilan.changeScore("45");
console.log(ilan);
```

this code runs me this error i doesn't get what i'v done wrong , please Help?
its a start but ,can't get why it doesnt work
thanks ahead

Comment: Don't initialize it again as javascript object. Remove this line ` ilan = {name:"Ilan Vachtel",currentMail:"ilanvac@gmail.com",currentScore:"85"};
`

Comment: @Ilan, please spend some time when writing question so others can spent less time helping you. I'll do the formatting this time but next time it's up to you.

Comment: Isthiscommenteasilyreadable?No?Thenyoumightconsiderspacesinyourcode,atleastwhenaskingothersforhelp.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, I got this question via review queue of first posts. Commented, and didn't get time to finish everything at once. Though I don't quite understand the situation "locked out" - ?

Comment: @Miki: It's one of the irritating aspects of the edit approval system. If I pick "Approve" rather than "Improve" then I can't edit until the edit as a whole has been approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `ilan` twice, first to an instance of the function, then to an object

```
var ilan = new Human();

ilan = {name:"Ilan Vachtel",currentMail:"ilanvac@gmail.com",currentScore:"85"};
```

Both of those are setting the value of `ilan`, and the last one is the one that sticks, and it has no `changeScore` property, hence the error when you're trying to call the `undefined` function.

Answer (score 2):

This line sets up an object using your `Human` function:

```
var ilan = new Human();
```

But then this line throws away that object and replaces it with a completely new object which has nothing whatsoever to do with what you did in your `Human` function:

```
ilan = {name:"Ilan Vachtel",currentMail:"ilanvac@gmail.com",currentScore:"85"};
```

Consequently, since that has nothing to do with `Human`, it doesn't have `changeScore`.

Given how `Human` is defined, you can replace those two lines and the `ilan.newScore = "89";` line that follows them with:

```
var ilan = new Human("Ilan Vachtel", "ilanvac@gmail.com", "85", "89");
```

...except that having a `newScore` argument to the constructor doesn't really make much sense.

Here's how that code would probably normally be written (see the comments):

```
function Human(name, currentMail, currentScore){
    this.name = name;
    this.currentMail = currentMail;
    this.currentScore = currentScore;
    // Having `newScore` here doesn't make any sense
}

Human.prototype.changeScore = function(ns) {
    if (ns != "") {
        console.log(ns+"Is Your New  Score");
        this.currentScore=ns;
    }
};

Human.prototype.changeMail = function(cmail) {
    if (cmail != this.currentMail) {
        console.log(cmail + "Is Your New Mail");
        this.currentMail = cmail; // <== `this.currentMail`, not `currrentMail`
    } // <== No ; here
};

var ilan = new Human("Ilan Vachtel", "ilanvac@gmail.com", "85");
ilan.changeScore("89");
console.log(ilan);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things missed here. First, the way your function should be initialized is with the `new` keyword, and not with a plain Object.

```
 var ilan = new Human();
 ilan = {name:"Ilan Vachtel",currentMail:"ilanvac@gmail.com",currentScore:"85"};
```

This is incorrect because it assigns ilan as an object. However, ilan was already a Function object constructed from `new Human`. Human takes four arguments in its constructor

```
function Human(name,currentMail,currentScore,newScore){
```

and you can take advantage of this by passing those arguments when you instantiate your Human object.

```
var ilan = new Human("Ilan Vachtel","ilanvac@gmail.com","85");//newScore will be undefined
console.log(ilan);//now will show a fully constructed object
ilan.newScore = "89";
ilan.changeScore("45");
console.log(ilan);
```

Also keep in mind that when using `this.changeScore = function` you are causing an anonymous function to be created every time a new Human is created. The suggested way of attaching this function is through the prototype like this:

```
//constructor function
function Human(name, currentMail, currentScore, newScore){
 this.name = name;
 this.currentMail = currentMail;
 this.currentScore = currentScore;
 this.newScore = newScore;
}

//prototype functions for Human
Human.prototype.changeScore = function(ns){
 if ( ns != "" ){
  console.log(ns+"Is Your New  Score");
  this.currentScore = ns;
 }
};

Human.prototype.changeMail = function( cmail ){
 if( cmail != this.currentMail ){
  console.log(cmail + "Is Your New Mail");
  this.currrentMail =  cmail;
 }
};
```